# GROUP BY return the first record

Tags: mysql, group-by

As far as I know mysql GROUP BY groups to the last record found.

Is there any solution to GROUP BY the first record?

I have setup the ORDER in SQL command and I need GROUP BY return the first record and not the last.

**EDIT**

Here is the Query

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(master.masterID),
  langData.*,
  master.* 
FROM master_table as master 
INNER JOIN lang_table as langData ON 
langData.masterID=master.masterID 
GROUP BY master.masterID 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN langData.lang='currentLang' THEN 1 ELSE 999 END , 
    master.name desc LIMIT 0,10
```

The query above select the `masterID` for multi language table and suppose to return FIRST the records in `currentLang` and order them by name AND THEN all other languages.

Don't ask me why I don't set the language in JOIN. This is the way to be done.

So everything works fine so far expect the scenario that I have a record with languages `en` and `fr`. If `currentLang` is `en` then based on

```
langData.lang='currentLang' THEN 1 ELSE 999 END
```

the `en` order is 1 and `fr` order is 999 and instead of getting the value of `en` I get the value of `fr`.

That's why I want to group to the first row.

Comment: I won't ask you why don't you set the language in the `JOIN`, rather I'll tell you that this way it will not work. An unaggregated expression in `GROUP BY` returns an arbitrary record from each group and is not supposed to be used if the values vary. You can return any record from `master_table` (they will all be the same within each group) but not from `lang_table`. There is no guarantee on which record will be returned, nada, niente. `BTW`, why do you have `DISTINCT` here, what's its purpose?

Comment: I am trying to achieve "give me first all records from current language order by name and then for all other languages order by name " Meaning : if current lang is EN then get all records for EN and then get all records for other langs.IF in lang table for one record has EN,FR return the EN value.IF in lang table EN does not exist return any other lang

Comment: this is very easy to do with a `JOIN` like described here: http://explainextended.com/2009/08/10/fallback-language-names-mysql/ but for some strange reason (which you don't even want to be asked for) you are reluctant to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume you are talking of something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        column
```

You shouldn't use unaggregated expressions in `GROUP BY` unless they are all same within the group.

If you want to return the record holding the least value of an expression within a group, use this:

```
SELECT  mo.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT column
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable mo
ON      mo.id = 
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.column = md.column
        ORDER BY
                mi.column, mi.someorder
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `LIMIT 1` to your query.