# Select unique rows, according to value in a secondary column

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a simple mysql table:

```
id, code, product_name, supplier
 1, 3844, ProductName1, Supplier1
 2, 3844, ProductName1, Supplier2
 3, 1233, ProductName2, Supplier2
```

I want to query all distinct products from table. So sql code is `select * from table group by code`.

**My problem**:

I want to set supplier priority in "group by" statement (e.g. Supplier1 is most relevant, but can be absent in list for a given `code`). Products #1 and #2 are the same. In my resulting table I want to see:

```
id, code, product_name, supplier
 1, 3844, ProductName1, Supplier1
 3, 1233, ProductName2, Supplier2
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248960), but using MS SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql GROUP BY return the first record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362720/mysql-group-by-return-the-first-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
SELECT
  MIN(id) id,
  code,
  MIN(product_name) product_name,
  MIN(supplier) supplier
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  (code, CASE WHEN supplier='Supplier1' THEN '' ELSE supplier END)
  IN (SELECT   code, min(CASE WHEN supplier='Supplier1' THEN '' ELSE supplier END)
      FROM     yourtable
      GROUP BY code)
GROUP BY
  code
ORDER BY
  min(id);
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15ab3/7).

Comment: hi, in this case the `MIN()` function works because the name given was `Supplier1`, and `Supplier2` what if the supplier were name like this `Walters Inc., Hummer, Brokage` and the OP wants to prioritize `Hummer`?

Comment: @JW yes you're right...this answer is not always correct... thanks

Comment: @JW updated.. i think that, if there are no empty values in supplier column, using `CASE WHEN` could do the trick

Comment: Could you give me some examples? Note: quantity of suppliers is 10+

Comment: @Dimitry see for example this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e9dc/1 if the supplier you want to prioritize is not present, it will just extract the first one in alphabetic order

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name    GROUP BY code    ORDER BY supplier
```

Comment: It is right in the simplest form. But what if @J W comment: what if the supplier were name like this Walters Inc., Hummer, Brokage and the OP wants to prioritize Hummer?

Comment: @Dimitry `SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY code ORDER BY supplier = "Walters Inc" DESC`