# closest values for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a table of prices of products, each price has a category. for each row representing a product I need to know the minimum range of prices in which the product price is contained, by product category

the expeced query should produce additional "expected L value" and "expected R value" columns.

the logic is:
    L value < price < R value
where
L value and R value are the closest prices of price

In the table below we have only an R value since no value are < of price
while for R value it is 12 since it is greater than price and it is also the closest.

Second row (ID 2) we have both L and R prices because:
10 (L price)  < 12 (price) < 32 (R price)
the L and R have to be calculated grouping by category

```
|  ID   | idcategory |  price  | expected L value  | expected R value  |
|   1   |     1      |   10    |         NULL      |         12        |
|   2   |     1      |   12    |         10        |         32        |
|   3   |     1      |   43    |         32        |         NULL      |
|   4   |     1      |   32    |         22        |         43        |
|   5   |     2      |   38    |         10        |         NULL      |
|   6   |     2      |    8    |         3         |         10        |
|   7   |     2      |    3    |         NULL      |          8        |
|   8   |     2      |   10    |          8        |         38        |
```

it is for postgres 9.2

Finally I got it by using lag and lead from partition, here the details:

```
--calculate the max
with prices_ord as (
  select idcategory , max(price)  max
  from prices
  group by idcategory 
),
--gets the l-r values with lag and lead from the partition sorted by price
interval_prices as (
  select  id, idcategory, price,
    lag(price, 1) over (partition by idcategory order by price) l_price,
    lead(price, 1) over (partition by idcategory order by price) r_price
  from prices
)
--returns the table joining by idcategory
select pi.* 
from prices_ord po
inner join interval_prices pi on po.idcategory= pi.idcategory
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql GROUP BY return the first record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362720/mysql-group-by-return-the-first-record)

Comment: Could provide your desired output?

Comment: dear user1066946: I don't see how this can be a duplicate, may you elaborate
dear Gordon Linoff: expected output are just columns "expected L value" and "expected R value". Will update the post

Comment: If `L` and `R` values are to be calculated, what is the exact logic?

Comment: Do you really believe that it's possible to understand what you mean by "*the closest prices of price*"?

Comment: Apologize for the english. Try again. Given a category I need to find a price interval in which the price is contained. this interval has to be the minimum. Hope this clarify.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need a separate CTE for `MAX()` - use windowing function `LAST_VALUE()` instead (which because of your ordering in the window, will return the max value).  Because optimizers are generally smart enough to combine identical windows, it may help query performance too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient query, but I can't think of a better one right now:

```
select p.id, 
       p.idcategory, 
       p.price, 
       (select max(lval.price) from prices lval where lval.price < p.price and lval.idcategory = p.idcategory) as l_value,
       (select min(rval.price) from prices rval where rval.price > p.price and rval.idcategory = p.idcategory) as r_value
from prices p
order by p.id;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8c0b/1

Comment: Hi, I found a solution and proposed it in the post. Will look more in details about performance against your solution. Thanks a lot